# In Postgres, how do I COUNT and WHERE in the same query, then do math on result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a large DB of `SALES_ORDERS`, that I need to determine the % each `SELLING_AGENT` had in the `ORDER`.

Learning postgresql, and this is just a sample, of ~500k rows of data.  Each `ORDER#` could be composed of dozens of `SALE_ITEM`s (but only composed of `'SALE_ITEM_1'` and `'SALE_ITEM_2'`).

I thought I could try doing a SUM SELECT something like this:

```
    SELECT (SUM(sale_item_1)+sum(sale_item_2)) as total_person_sale
    FROM SALES_ORDER
    WHERE orderNumber LIKE orderNumber
    GROUP by SELLING_AGENT
```

But clearly I'm not grasping the WHERE statement use to count similar

The hope is to fill out the final column, like this: 
selling agent:

```
    selling agent:  Order#  Sale_item_1 Sale_item_2 %_of_TOTAL_order
    jim              abc    $1.00       $2.00       14.29%
    steve            abc    $3.00       $4.00       33.33%
    carl             abc    $5.00       $6.00       52.38%
    carl             def    $7.00       $8.00       31.25%
    steve            def    $9.00       $9.00       37.50%
    jim              def    $8.00       $7.00       31.25%
    steve            ghi    $6.00       $5.00       61.11%
    patty            ghi    $4.00       $3.00       38.89%
```

Comment: What are `SALES_ORDERS`, `SELLING_AGENT`, and `sales_db`?

Comment: Please  post sample data and table structures so the community can try and help you  out.

Comment: @melpomene - thanks, I edited the query to point correct.  Thanks for understanding, it is my first post!  So SALES_ORDERS is the DB itself.  SELLING_AGENT is the person that made the sale.  sales_db is my (incorrectly) named table, that I just fixed.

Comment: @GMB - thanks also!  So again new to this setup, not sure the best way to post it, but he's a screenshot of the sample DB: http://prntscr.com/m3k840 . --will that work?

Comment: Also, just in general, WOW, I did not expect this type of quick response here!  I've used stackoverflow to just get answers, but never posted.  Thanks for the quick feedback from all of you. Very cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  s.*, 
  ROUND (
  100.00 * (s.sale_item_1 + s.sale_item_2) /
  (SELECT 
     SUM(sale_item_1 + sale_item_2)
     FROM sales_db 
     WHERE orderNumber = s.orderNumber), 2) percentage
FROM sales_db s;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=778c02bcc70d02da636fad6e0261eec7)

Comment: Ooh, this one is right there!  http://prntscr.com/m3kbmq

As per the question, I think you solved it! That being said, I have an add-on question, please let me know if I need to create a new question or such (or do I add this comment in the "overall question?"  

They added "store_name" which is a location of "North" or "South" --Note the screenshot in this thread.  Rows 5,7,8 ( also 6 and 9) are ALL the same ORDER, but different "store_name".  How can I add one more variable in there to parse the 2 "store_name" fields also? So Row5's "percentage" would be 42.8%(3/7), and Row8's 100%(5/5)?

Comment: I think it's better to post a new question, with not only this screenshot, but also a lot more explanation and the **expected result**.

Comment: Ok!  I will!  Thank you very much @forpas --you rule!

Comment: I'll put a link in here to the new question.  I have a better understanding of how to post/edit on here now, so I'll be sure to make it clearer/cleaner! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058258/add-an-extra-where-clause-to-a-working-query-to-further-sort-by-percentage

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do something that is somewhat advanced. I'll give you two options:

```
SELECT selling_agent, orderNumber,
    sum(sale_item_1) as sale_item_1,
    sum(sale_item_2) as sale_item_2,
    (sum(sale_item_1) + sum(sale_item_2)) * 100.00 /
        sum(sum(sale_item_1) + sum(sale_item_2)) over (partition by orderNumber) as orderPercentage
FROM sales_db
--WHERE orderNumber LIKE orderNumber /* I'm not sure what this is about */
GROUP by orderNumber, selling_agent
ORDER BY orderNumber, selling_agent
```

This is the old way via a subquery:

```
SELECT selling_agent, orderNumber,
    sum(sale_item_1) as sale_item_1,
    sum(sale_item_2) as sale_item_2,
    (sum(sale_item_1) + sum(sale_item_2)) * 100.00 /
        (
        select sum(sale_item_1 + sale_item_2)
        from sales_db s2
        where s2.orderNumber = s.orderNumber
        )
FROM sales_db s
--WHERE orderNumber LIKE orderNumber
GROUP by orderNumber, selling_agent
ORDER BY orderNumber, selling_agent
```

By the way, if each selling agent is only represented once per order number this could be simplified a bit.

Comment: Trying this one (and I realize I gave a typo in the above, so my bad!) gave me an error: http://prntscr.com/m3k9rv
[42803] ERROR: column "sales_orders_test.sale_price_1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 180

Comment: This works, aside from the 2 decimal place in the % column!  http://prntscr.com/m3kox2 . I added an addition to the query as you can see from the response posted below, where I add in a "store_name" variable as well to sort that specific piece also.  I liked the "round" function as well, and tried with your code: `Round((sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)) * 100.00 /
        sum(sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)),2) ` but got `aggregate function cannot be nested` with it.  I'll post the link to the other question here if you'd like!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058258/add-an-extra-where-clause-to-a-working-query-to-further-sort-by-percentage