# Add an extra WHERE clause to a working query to further sort by percentage

Tags: postgresql

Need to be able to populate the PERCENT_OF_TOTAL_ORDER column, with a WHERE filter on STORE_LOCATION.

I had some great answers to the first question around parsing the data, and learned how better to describe my request here: [In Postgres, how do I COUNT and WHERE in the same query, then do math on result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055923/in-postgres-how-do-i-count-and-where-in-the-same-query-then-do-math-on-result)

So the second part of the request is to be able to now write the data back to the `PERCENT_OF_TOTAL_ORDER` column using the data in the `STORE_LOCATION` field, based on the `PERCENT_OF_TOTAL_ORDER` being .  NOTE: Store location will ONLY be `north` or `south`.

The current state of the DB looks like this: http://prntscr.com/m3ktu4 . There are several `<NULL>` entries in the `PERCENT_OF_TOTAL_ORDER` column, while some are filled in.  That is the column I'll be wanting to populate.  So I think I want to do a `SELECT` statement and `WHERE` clause to `SET` the `PERCENT_OF_TOTAL`.

This actual table is currently ~500k+ rows, with ~50k different `ORDER_NUMBER`s so looking for the most efficient code to update the current data, and then plan to set the code as a CRON job to update nightly going forward.

From the previous post, mentioned above, both these 2 solutions get the % correct, but do not populate the `PERCENT_OF_TOTAL_ORDER` column.

Solution1:

```
    SELECT selling_agent, order_number,
           sum(sale_price_1) as sale_price_1,
           sum(sale_price_2) as sale_price_2,
           (sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)) * 100.00 / sum(sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)) over (partition by order_number) as orderPercentage
    FROM sales_orders_test
    GROUP by order_number, selling_agent
    ORDER BY order_number, selling_agent
```

Solution 2:

```
    SELECT s.*,
    ROUND (100.00 * (s.sale_price_1 + s.sale_price_2) /
    (SELECT
    SUM(sale_price_1 + sale_price_2)
    FROM sales_orders_test
    WHERE order_number = s.order_Number), 2) percentage
    FROM sales_orders_test s;
```

I tried to add a `WHERE` clause on Solution 2 with this:

```
    UPDATE sales_orders_test
    SET percent_of_total_order =
    (
    SELECT selling_agent, order_number,
    sum(sale_price_1) as sale_price_1,
    sum(sale_price_2) as sale_price_2,
    (sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)) * 100.00 /
    sum(sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)) over (partition by order_number) as orderPercentage
    FROM sales_orders_test
    GROUP by order_number, selling_agent
    ORDER BY order_number, selling_agent
    )

    WHERE percent_of_total_order IS NULL
```

...and it gave me `[42601] ERROR: subquery must return only one column`

How can I get the percentage into the column, based on the `STORE_LOCATION`, to be updated based on this info?

The planned output is the table being populated this one time, then nightly, with an end result like this: http://prntscr.com/m3l3fz

EDIT: @used_by_already's suggestion (thank you), here is the DB as it looks now:

```
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------------+----------------+
    | pk_id | selling_agent | order_number | sale_price_1 |         sale_price_2 | percent_of_total_order | store_location |
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
    |     1 | jim           |          123 |            1 |                    2 |                        | south          |
    |     2 | steve         |          123 |            1 |                    3 |                        | south          |
    |     3 | carl          |          123 |            1 |                    4 |                        | north          |
    |     4 | carl          |          456 |            1 |                    5 |                        | north          |
    |     5 | steve         |          456 |            1 |                    5 |                        | north          |
    |     6 | jim           |          456 |            1 |                    6 |                  36.84 | north          |
    |     7 | steve         |          789 |            1 |                   78 |                        | south          |
    |     8 | patty         |          789 |            1 |                    7 |                        | north          |
    |     9 | bob           |          187 |            3 |                    3 |                    100 | south          |
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----------        ---+------------------------+----------------+
```

Here is the code as I'd like it to look:

```
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------------------+----------------+
    | pk_id | selling_agent | order_number | sale_price_1 |         sale_price_2 | percent_of_total_order | store_location |
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
    |     1 | jim           |          123 |            1 |                    2 |                  42.86 | south          |
    |     2 | steve         |          123 |            1 |                    3 |                  57.14 | south          |
    |     3 | carl          |          123 |            1 |                    4 |                  100   | north          |
    |     4 | carl          |          456 |            1 |                    5 |                  27.27 | north          |
    |     5 | steve         |          456 |            1 |                    5 |                  40.91 | north          |
    |     6 | jim           |          456 |            1 |                    6 |                  31.82 | north          |
    |     7 | steve         |          789 |            1 |                   78 |                  100   | south          |
    |     8 | patty         |          789 |            1 |                    7 |                  100   | north          |
    |     9 | bob           |          187 |            3 |                    3 |                  100   | south          |
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----------        ---+------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You have moved from a select statement (where multiple rows are allowed) to an update statement where you are only permitted a single value. In your current query you are trying to squeeze multiple values into each "slot" where only one value is allowed.

Comment: To get faster resolution provide **sample data** (as reusable text, not images) as well as the **expected result** (text preferred over images). Here is a site that helps prepare text tables: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/  *Why are images not liked?* Imagine if our suggested solutions were images of SQL, would you find the transcription effort of that frustrating?

Comment: @Used_By_Already --thank you for the pointer!  Updated!

Answer (score 1):

I got it!  So I figured I'd share it here!

```
    WITH perc_sales as (


SELECT pk_id,
       selling_agent,
       order_number,
       store_location,
       sum(sale_price_1)                                                           as Sale1,
       sum(sale_price_2)                                                           as Sale2,
       ROUND((sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2)) * 100.00 /
             GREATEST(sum(sum(sale_price_1) + sum(sale_price_2))
                          over (partition by order_number, store_location), 1), 2) as orderPercentage
FROM sales_orders_test
GROUP BY pk_id
)
UPDATE sales_orders_test AS PERC_UPDATE
SET percent_of_total_order = PS.orderPercentage
FROM perc_sales PS
WHERE PS.pk_id = PERC_UPDATE.pk_id;
```

That gives me:

```
    +-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
| pk_id | selling_agent | order_number | sale_price_1 | sale_price_2 | percent_of_total_order | store_location |
+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
|     1 | jim           |          123 |            1 |            2 |                  42.86 | south          |
|     2 | steve         |          123 |            1 |            3 |                  57.14 | south          |
|     3 | carl          |          123 |            1 |            4 |                    100 | north          |
|     4 | carl          |          456 |            1 |            5 |                  27.27 | north          |
|     5 | steve         |          456 |            1 |            8 |                  40.91 | north          |
|     6 | jim           |          456 |            1 |            6 |                  31.82 | north          |
|     7 | steve         |          789 |            1 |           78 |                    100 | south          |
|     8 | patty         |          789 |            1 |            7 |                    100 | north          |
|     9 | bob           |          187 |            3 |            3 |                    100 | south          |
+-------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

Thanks all for the tips!